# How many nodes can connected to a single channel?

Tags: lora

I'm new to LORA technology. I'm gonna build a single channel gateway using ESP32 and 2 LoRa nodes to demo.

How many nodes can connected to a single channel?

Answer (score 0):

It depends... If your nodes are close to the gateway and are transmitting small bits of data more nodes can transmit to it. Whereas more data or further away means more time on air. It is also important to realize that a single channel gateway has a third of the channels a normal gateway has up to even one eighth of the possible amount of channels.

[Some simulations have been done](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-many-devices-does-one-lorawan-gateway-support-120-jay-wey). "Their simulation results: A single LoRaWAN gateway can support 120 end devices, assuming each end device transmits 20 bytes every 16.7 minutes."

And here is Murata's [answer](https://www.murata.com/en-eu/support/faqs/products/lpwa/lora/hardware/0009) to the question for a 8 channel gateway: "For instance, if there is a 8-channel Gateway supporting 1.5M packets/day, and if the application sends 1 packet per hour, then more than 62,000 nodes can be handled by that Gateway."